# Typescript public function

Tags: javascript, typescript, kendo-ui

In TypeScript I have this simple code:

```
namespace Customer {
   function onOpen() {
   }
 }
```

It generates:

```
var Customer;
(function (Customer) {
    function onOpen() {
    }
})(Customer || (Customer = {}));
```

In order for Kendo to use `onOpen` the JS needs to look like this (Notice the `onOpen`). Is this possible?:

```
var Customer;
(function (Customer) {
    Customer.onOpen = function () {
    }
})(Customer || (Customer = {}));
```

Comment: Are you getting an error at runtime with KendoUI? If so, can you add that? It would surprise me if that is the case, as there isn't much difference in those declarations. You could perhaps set a property that is a function instead of a method, I can write an answer for that. But adding the console error would be helpful.

Comment: Actually disregard my comment, @MinusFour got it right - your function is just not exposed / exported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to export exposed properties, and since functions are first class citizens, you can write typescript code like this :

```
namespace Customer {
  export const onOpen = () => {}
}
```

Or instead of a lambda just with normal function

```
namespace Customer {
  export const onOpen = function() {}
}
```

Or this will work

```
namespace Customer {
  export function onOpen() { }
}
```

That will generate a property that points to a function instead of a function member - essentially the same thing really.

Javascript output:

```
var Customer;
(function (Customer) {
    Customer.onOpen = function () { };
})(Customer || (Customer = {}));
```

Answer (score 5):

Add `export`:

```
namespace Customer {
   export function onOpen() {
   }
 }
```

Produces:

```
var Customer;
(function (Customer) {
    function onOpen() {
    }
    Customer.onOpen = onOpen;
})(Customer || (Customer = {}));
```